# Why can I drop table when logged in as not owner?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, pgadmin, drop-table

I read that only owner can drop table and no other user may be granted to do so.

I created a table with owner `postgres` and then drop it as another user. What privileges should I revoke to disallow it?

The user has all the privileges granted by default in db properties but I don't see any "create table" or "drop table" privilege.

Comment: Please show the output from `\dt+ droppable_table` and `\du non_postgres_user`, issued from `psql`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Superusers** are always exempt from lowly permission checks. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/role-attributes.html)

> superuser status
>
> A database superuser bypasses all permission checks, except the right
> to log in. This is a dangerous privilege and should not be used carelessly; ...

To see whether your [current user is a superuser](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-show.html):

```
SHOW IS_SUPERUSER;
```

To list all superuser roles:

```
SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE rolsuper;
```

And the **schema owner** can do it, too. The [documentation for `DROP TABLE`:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-droptable.html)

> Only the table owner, the schema owner, and superuser can drop a table.

To list schema-owners:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name, pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS owner
FROM   pg_namespace n
WHERE  n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
AND    n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER  BY 1;
```

About the same as `\dn` in psql.

[And who are you?](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE)

```
SELECT current_user, session_user;
```

Comment: Is it possible to disallow schema owner to drop tables?

Comment: @Vlad: I don't think so. Either make the superuser (postgres) own the schema or use the same owner for schema and table to avoid the split.